# Robo 3T connect to a database and dropDatabases programatically

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have multiple databases on mongo, let's say `mydb`, `mydb1`, `mydb2`, `mydb3`, `mydb4`.

Sometimes I want to drop all these databases except `mydb`. It is a process that I do manually, right click in the mouse -> `Drop Database`.

I am looking for commands that I can execute to change the database in Robo 3T, where I am connected to and be able to drop the database, without using the mouse, or query the database.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you asking about the commands or about executing commands in robo 3t?

Comment: @deadshot sorry I was not clear, Robo3T is executing commands behind the scenes to do this jobs, I want to execute manually to avoid using the mouse. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mongo shell you could run

```
db.getSiblingDB("database name").dropDatabase()
```

Not sure of that will run in Robo3T